# Android - Layout question - Textviews top center and bottom center

Tags: android, layout, center, textview

I have a layout question.

Say I have a RelativeLayout appearing at the bottom of my screen. In this, I want to add 2 textviews, in the center, one in the top center and one in the bottom center.

```
|--------------------------|
|          Text1           |
|          Text2           |
|--------------------------|
```

Something like that :-)

Comment: your question is misguiding..you have put the "image" from which first i came to know that you required 2 textviews at screen's "Center-hozontal"...instead it, you should put image which contains One TExt at Top and One text at bottom

Comment: @Paresh - could you please elaborate? I seem to understand his requirement clearly but not what you are trying to say...

Comment: @Shouvik...he put the image which is not showing as per his requirement "one textview in top center and one in bottom center"..i hope you got it

Answer (score 1):

How's this work for you:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:gravity="center_horizontal">
    <TextView android:id="@+id/text1"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:text="Text 1"/>   
    <TextView android:id="@+id/text2"
              android:layout_below="@id/text1"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:text="Text 2"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Both the textview are appeared at "Center horizontal"...he asked that "one in top center and one in bottom center"

Comment: This'll work if he wants it just like the text picture he drew in the question... but he's disappeared so we'll never know :)